# BlockingScheduler is not working when building tkinter using pyinstaller

Tags: python, tkinter, scheduler, pyinstaller

I have a tkinter python script which alerts me at defined time. All works fine. Now i want to make this application executable through pyinstaller. When i run **pyinstaller filename.py**, it also creates all dependencies files. But clicking **.exe** file is not working/opening my application. mention you that i'm using ubuntu 16.1. Below is my code.

```
import time
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler
import logging
import urlparse
import urllib
import urllib2
import simplejson
from Tkinter import *



logging.basicConfig()

def auto_timer():
    global time, urllib2, simplejson
    today_date = time.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")

    response = urllib2.urlopen("http://localhost/tk_dev/index.php/json/python_tkinter_effort_notice/118")
    data = simplejson.load(response)
    data_status = data["ma_effort_date"]  # 2017-02-19


    global root100
    root100 = Tk()


    if data_status != today_date:
        root100.attributes('-zoomed', True)
        root100.title("Notification")
        label = Label(root100, width="100",  text="Your didn't effort today. \nTime to do this job now. . . \nHurry up!!!")
        label.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True, padx=20, pady=20)

        button = Button(text = 'Close')
        button.pack(side="bottom", fill="none", expand=True)

        root100.mainloop()




not_executed = 1

while(not_executed):
    dt = list(time.localtime())
    hour = dt[3]
    minute = dt[4]


    if hour == 20 and minute == 40:
        scheduler = BlockingScheduler()
        scheduler.add_job(auto_timer, 'interval', hours=0.002)
        scheduler.start()
        not_executed = 0
```